# How does an "account" work with AWS Identity Token Vending Machine?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've followed the instructions in this post http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx371Y7CA0QJ95X/Simplifying-Token-Vending-Machine-Deployment-with-AWS-CloudFormation

And I can see that it's working somewhat, and i understand the overall concept of what TVM is and why it's needed, however I still have hard time understanding how this works in practicality. I read a post somewhere that anonymous token vending machine is designed for read-only and if I wanted to actually provide write access I need to use identity TVM.

In the demo app it makes me register my account on the cloudformation server i set up, but I don't understand how this works with say my own web app. I have a mobile app that connects to rails app where I need users to upload their profile images as well as post photo content. I already have the app running except for the integration part with the TVM (basically my aws credentials are embedded in the app which Amazon doesn't recommend)

So my question is how do i integrate an existing REST based iOS app with identity token vending machine to upload photos to S3? How can i integrate it without making users separately create an "account" for the identity token vending machine on top of registering for my app?

Answer (score 1):

We recently launched [Amazon Cognito](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/), which obviates the need for the TVM in many cases, particularly in the "anonymous TVM" case. Through Cognito's unauthenticated access you can grant users of your application limited access privileges to various AWS resources. Cognito leverages existing functionality of IAM Roles and STS to deliver these credentials.

If you want to maintain the integration with your existing backend authentication solution, you will need to generate and maintain the list of identity ids for your application. You can read more about the APIs involved in our [API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/).

Answer (score 0):

Your app can act as the TVM, mapping your user identities to the IAM Roles with the permissions they need. Then can use the AssumeRole calls on STS to create temporary credentials for these users. Your app then creates a S3Client object with these credentials and use it to upload the photo.

See the "Identity federation" and "Web identity federation" sections of the of [IAM Roles documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/WorkingWithRoles.html)

The [AWS Web Identity Federation Playground](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/the-aws-web-identity-federation-playground) is a nice example app to see it at work.

CoudFormation will automate the creation, updates and deletion of AWS Resources, including EC2 Instances and IAM Roles, but will not be directly related to the user authentication.